# What does @/="" do in Vim?

Tags: vim

The symbol `/` is forward research, so I guess it means: what is stored is the forward research (i.e. `/`) register (`@`) needs to be replaced (`=`) by the empty string (`""`). Is it correct?

Any other registers like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its own, `@/=""` means nothing.

If you prepend it with `:help :let`:

```
:let @/=""
```

then it means "set the `@/` register to an empty string", which is a way of emptying it.

You can do that with any writable register. See `:help registers` to figure out which ones are writable and which ones are read-only.

Example uses:

```
" put the name of the current file in the system clipboard
:let @+ = @%
" put the last Ex command in the system clipboard
:let @+ = @:
" put the last Ex command in register a for later use
:let @a = @:
```

Note that this is a quick and *dirty* method. `:help setreg()` is much cleaner but it is too verbose for casual use.